# how do i calculate stall torque 5.4kg@ 5v 1000mA?

Tags: servo, torque

i came to this website https://www.letsbuyrobots.com/en/robot-humanoide-ls-868, and i want to know the servo spec especially the stall torque, and then i found this "2) Torque:5.4kg@5v 1000mA, Power: 5-9V Operation", what does this even mean?, how do i know the servo stall torque from that?, thanks

Comment: kg is not a measure of torque. This does not bode well for the accuracy of the datasheet.

Comment: You are correct. That is not something that you should buy. Unfortunately, there are a huge number of web sites attempting to sell things without adequate specifications. You can attempt to contact them and request decent information or you can look elsewhere. I recommend you look elsewhere.

Comment: "kg is not a measure of torque", yea, i am confused too when i see this, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty reasonable to assume they mean kg-cm. The size and form factor of that motor both corroborate this assumption. You can't be sure that is the stall torque, since they did not say that was the stall torque. You also can't determine the stall torque from that number, since stall torque is dependent on the maximum current of the motor. My suspicion is that the stall torque is 2-3x higher than that based on the size of the robot, but that's complete speculation.